# When the router is acting as a proxy DNS, computer can't know the real DNS address?

Tags: dns

[This very old question](https://superuser.com/questions/85887/how-to-find-out-dns-server-ip-used-by-my-router) has an answer that says:

> If your router is passing itself as the DNS server, then you should be able to go on the router's admin interface status page and see what DNS servers it got from comcast's DHCP server.

Is that the only way? That is, there is no way programmatically to get the real DNS server address within my computer, without opening the router web page? I have tried things like "ipconfig /all" or "nslookup", but none of those show the REAL DNS address that I see in the router web page.

Comment: yeah, that is more or less correct. when a DNS server is used as a resolver for domains it doesn't carry, it will usually be configured as "recursive" and will complete all the subqueries before responding to the client with a single answer. that answer will appear to the client to be coming from the DNS resolver.  I don;t believe the DNS datagram format allows the client to determine the authoritative server.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thank you, sir.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out DNS server IP used by my router](https://superuser.com/questions/85887/how-to-find-out-dns-server-ip-used-by-my-router)